# Why test method fails?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a create method to create entities trough `POST`:

```
  def create = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    val address = Json.fromJson[Address](request.body)
    Ok(address.toString())
  }
```

I want to test it like:

```
 "A POST request on addresses create method" should "return OK " in {
    val node = Json.toJson(Address(None, "street 2", "33", "343333", "Arad", "Romania", None))(controllers.AddressBean.addressWrites);
    val result = AddressBean.create(FakeRequest().withJsonBody(node, Helpers.POST))

    status(result) should equal(OK)
    contentType(result) should be(Some("application/json"))
  }
```

but seems strange to me this warning about `status(result)`:

> type mismatch; found :
>   play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte],play.api.mvc.Result]
>   required: play.api.mvc.Result

Does anyone knows why this type mismatch happens?

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting here the solution I received from James, on google groups, maybe will be useful to others:

> Unfortunately this confusion comes from there being two apply methods on Action, one that accepts RequestHeader, and one that
>   accepts Request[A], where A must be the type of the body that the
>   action accepts.  Hence, if you pass a request with the wrong body
>   type, it will use the RequestHeader apply method, which is what
>   returns the iteratee.
>
> So, your problem is that your passing the wrong body type. 
>   withJsonBody passes a content type of AnyContent, which is what gets
>   used when you don't explicitly specify a parser in your action.  But
>   you're using parse.json, which means the body is a JsonNode.  So, try
>   something like this:

```
new FakeRequest(Helpers.POST, "/", FakeHeaders(), node)
```

so in the end my `POST` test method (using scalatest) looks like:

```
    "A POST request on addresses create method" should "return OK " in {
    val node = Json.toJson(Address(Some(12), "street 2", "33", "343333", "Arad", "Romania", None))(controllers.AddressBean.addressWrites);
    val result = AddressBean.create(new FakeRequest(Helpers.POST, "/", FakeHeaders(), node))

    status(result) should equal(OK)
    contentType(result) should be(Some("application/json"))
  }
```